# Optimal Wi-Fi channels in 2.4 GHz

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

Everybody is talking about 1, 6 and 11 being the best channels. But nobody is differentiating between `802.11b`, `g` or `n`.

I found this illustration, which shows the channels that don't overlap for the different kinds of Wi-Fi. It's from the German Wikipedia, so it contains channels 12, 13 and 14 too. And these are for me, as I live in Germany, possible channels to use.

[image: Non overlapping channels]

What I didn't find was an explanation of which channels are best to use if more than one kind of Wi-Fi networks exist in the same area. In my case there are both `802.11g/n` networks as well as `802.11n-only` networks, some using 20 MHz-wide channels and some using 40 MHz-wide channels.

So what are the best channels to use, if the Wi-Fi networks in the area are using both 20MHz and 40MHz-wide channels?

Comment: Once 40MHz-wide channels show up in 2.4GHz in your neighborhood, it's time to move to 5GHz.

Comment: Let's assume that 5 GHz isn't an option right now!

Comment: As per specifications, 40 MHz mode must not be used if there are other networks on any “affected” channel. This essentially means you cannot use 40 MHz channels, ever. Unless you live in the middle of nowhere. Just turn it off, it’s plenty fast even without it.

Comment: I edited your question because you were misusing the terms a bit. 802.11n can use 40MHz-wide channels, but it doesn't have to. For example, you can have an 802.11n-only network on 20MHz-wide channels, and you can also have an 802.11b/g/n network in 20/40MHz mode.

Answer (score 1):

Simple - the one thats in least use, and the best way to find this out is with a site survey.

I favour doing a site survey - I find that a mobile phone or tablet with inssider (I use [Android on my phones, so this is what I use](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.metageek) ) or some other network scanner is a great tool for this - it shows you what channels are in use (and how many APs are using it and overlapping channels) and which ones are using 40 mhz and 20 mhz channels.

Comment: But still my question is:
if the optimal channels for wifi g+n are: 1,5,9 and 13
and the optimal channels for wifi n are: 3 and 11
and they show up in the same area,
are the optimal channels then only the two from wifi n, or still for both kinds of wifi the dedicated ones?